# Канцелярит

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте! Встретился текст для написания из ЕГЭ по русскому языку, повествующий о вреде и призывающий бороться с канцеляритом. Какие литературные аргументы (наверное, именно из художественной литературы, не из статей, например) можно привести к данной теме? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

"Изгоните бюрократизм из человеческих отношений, из быта, и тогда он уйдет сам собою из писем, учебников, диссертаций, литературоведческих книг" (К. Чуковский).

У Зощенко есть рассказ "Обезьяний язык", в нем, как и во многих других, он высмеивает людей, употребляющих канцеляризмы в обыденной жизни.

http://ostrovok.de/old/classics/zoshchenko/story079.htm

А.Платонов использует канцелярит в речи героев — это скрытая ирония. Автор нарочно коверкает фразу, чтобы показать нелепость происходящего: “умолкнувшим образом”, “будучи убитым”. Язык автора — это подчинение языку эпохи, это стиль штампов и лозунгов. Он передает речь увлеченных полуграмотных ораторов... “Религия — это предрассудки и самогон...” Оказалось, что русский язык потерян. Остались одни словесные уродцы, “рожа революции”. Слово в произведении Платонова передает одновременно и мысль, и ее восприятие автором или героем: “На дороге встречались худые деревья, горькая горелая трава и всякий другой живой и мертвый инвентарь природы”. 
 Повесть “Сокровенный человек” заканчивается великолепным диалогом у моря. Вдали от начальства, Фома Пухов идет принимать паровоз у напарника и говорит: 
    — Прекрасное утро,— а тот отвечает: 
    — Да, вполне революционное... А что революция несет людям?

Есть хорошая пародия:
А.Кнышев
ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЕ

Внимание!
Розжиг костров,
выгул собак,
отлов рыбы и отстрел дичи,
выпас и выгон скота,
а также
выполз змей,
выпорос свиней,
выжереб коней и выкобыл лошадей,
вымет икры,
вылуп птиц из яиц,
выкукол бабочек и выхухол выхухолей,
выкур курей и выпрыг кенгурей,
обгад ромашек,
обдир ягод,
выруб леса и вылом веток,
выслеж зайца,
мыслишь верно,
выпуг тетерева,
выдох вдоха,
вынос тела,
вы нас за нос - мы вас по уху,
выхлоп газов,
выкидыш мусора,
выводок гусей,
выродок людей,
выплав стали,
выплыв сели,
выпендр фраеров,
выстрел Аврор,
выклянч денег,
вымуштр солдат,
вытрус половиков,
выпал из окна,
выпор детей,
выдрем в гамаках, вытрем губ и выпуч глаз,
вычих насморка,
вытреп и разбрех государственных тайн,
выкус накоси и накось выкуси,
окот, отел и атас,
а главное,
загляд и залаз в дупла с выкуром оттуда пчел
и распробом меда
ЗАПРЕЩЕН И ПРЕКРАЩЕН
в связи с отказом их от высоса нектара
после выщипа цветов и выдерга травы,
а также в связи с полным вымером.

Answer (score 0):

Канцелярит подробно описан К. Чуковским в книге «Живой как жизнь».